# how to show and hide the progress bar in webview - android

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar

i work in web app and try to show and hide the progress bar but its not working . also i use the slide drawer to show this web when the user click on the handle button . so here is the java code i use

```
        tweb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.twitter_web);
    WebSettings webSettings1 = tweb.getSettings();
    webSettings1.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);    
    tweb.loadUrl("https://www.twitter.com");    
    tweb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    class viewclient_twitter extends WebViewClient {

             @Override
             public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

              super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
              findViewById(R.id.progressBar2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              findViewById(R.id.textView2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

             }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            findViewById(R.id.progressBar2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.textView2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
```

and here is the xml code

```
    <SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/twitter_slide"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/handle"
        android:nextFocusRight="@+id/handlee"

         />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/progressBar2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar2"
            android:text="Loading. . ."
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/twitter_web"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

so please how can i make this progress bar show and hide after the page loading finish??

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i fixed,

```
protected ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private static final int SHOW_PROGRESS = 0x01;
private static final int STOP_PROGRESS = 0x02;
```

creating webview client will help you here,

```
WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings();
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

// Showing progress here.
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(STOP_PROGRESS);
        // animate(view);
    }

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(STOP_PROGRESS);
        Utils.displayToast("We are sorry! " + description,
                CommonWebView.this);
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }

});

Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {

        case SHOW_PROGRESS:
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = Utils
                        .createProgressDialog(CommonWebView.this);
// Create your own progress and show here.

                progressDialog.show();

            } else {
                progressDialog.show();

            }
            mHandler.removeMessages(SHOW_PROGRESS);
            break;

        case STOP_PROGRESS:
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            mHandler.removeMessages(STOP_PROGRESS);
            break;
        }
    };
};
```